# How can I document a knockout.js view model with jsdoc?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, jsdoc

I already tried to make use of namespaces and the @memberOf tag, but in the generated API doc I still have no class members or methods at all.

Here is some example code:

```
/**
 * Test file
 * @namespace test
 */

/**
 * my view model
 * @class MyViewModel
 * @memberOf test
 */
function MyViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    /**
     * test observable
     * @type {Object}
     * @memberOf test.MyViewModel#
     */
    self.testObservable = ko.observable();

    /**
     * test function
     * @memberOf test.MyViewModel#
     */
    self.testObservable = function() {
        // do something
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `@memberof` tags would work if you used `@memberof!`. The exclamation point forces jsdoc to follow what you give it. If you don't use the exclamation point, jsdoc will decide that it knows better than you do and ignore the tag. But using `@memberof!` still makes it look funky. What you can do is remove the `@memberof` tags and use `@lends` as follows:

```
/**
 * Test file
 * @namespace test
 */

/**
 * my view model
 * @class MyViewModel
 * @memberOf test
 */
function MyViewModel() {
    /** @lends test.MyViewModel# */
    var self = this;

    /**
     * test observable
     * @type {Object}
     */
    self.testObservable = ko.observable();

    /**
     * test function
     */
    self.testObservable = function() {
        // do something
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

jsdoc appears to be confused when you attach your variable to `self`. JSDoc actually parses your code to find the name of variables doesn't seem able to handle the way you're defining properties on your classes. (Although that's a pretty common way to define them).

I ran this code through jsdoc and it documented just fine:

```
/**
 * Test file
 * @namespace test
 */

/**
 * my view model
 * @class MyViewModel
 * @memberOf test
 */
function MyViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    /**
     * test observable
     * @type {Object}
     * @memberOf test.MyViewModel#
     */
    var testObservable = ko.observable();
}
```

you could make that work like this:

```
/**
 * Test file
 * @namespace test
 */

/**
 * my view model
 * @class MyViewModel
 * @memberOf test
 */
function MyViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    /**
     * test observable
     * @type {Object}
     * @memberOf test.MyViewModel#
     */
    var testObservable = self.testObservable = ko.observable();
}
```

That seems like a pretty annoying way to have to do it though :(

### My Suggestion

Use **[yuidoc](http://yui.github.io/yuidoc/)** which doesn't parse your javascript at all, but instead depends you explicitly describing each property. Here's how I would document your code with yuidoc:

```
/**
 * Test file
 * @namespace test
 */

/**
 * my view model
 * @class MyViewModel
 * @memberOf test
 */
function MyViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    /**
     * test observable
     * @property testObservable
     * @type {Object}
     */
    self.testObservable = ko.observable();

    /**
     * test function
     * @property testObservable
     */
    self.testObservable = function() {
        // do something
    };
}
```